# How to merge posts from 5 different website and import one post to drupal by feeds

Tags: views, importing-exporting, feeds

I want to create a music reference website With drupal 7.So explain my diagram and want to help me .

I specified 5 other music website that give direct download link to users.in other 5 sites musics post with a title + description + download links.such as all other websites that post download music or software.
I want to take ONE post Title of these websites + ALL direct links and import to drupal .So for every imported music post I have a Title + 5 download direct link from 5 defferent website.So user can Go to my site and download A music from 5 download link from 5 defferent sites.

1- I can give Titles of new posts from feed (rss) of these sites.

2- How Can I merge 5 titles of these sites to One title (equivalent music titles) - for example titles of one website post is "free download of music from SINGER called SONGNAME" . 
This Title take and other 4 sites title merge or ignore Then Download links Attached (link url ONLY) to same Post.

3- I want to import and show only URL of Download links to user.without upload it to drupal or filefield modules.only url.no file.

please Help me.how can I do it? 
I Worked with [feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module previously.